# For which n $\phi(n) | n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can you simplify this messy proof of mine please ? And is it even correct?

Let n = $p_{1} ^{a_1}p_{2}^{a_2}...p_{n}^{a_n}$ .
Now write $\phi(n)$ as $p_{1}^{a_1 -1}p_{2}^{a_2 -1}...p_{n}^{a_n -1}(p_1 -1)(p_2 -1)...(p_n -1)$. 
From $\phi(n)|n$
$$\implies (p_1-1)(p_2-1)...(p_n-1)|p_1p_2...p_n$$
$$\iff (p_1-1)(p_2-1)...(p_n-1)d=p_1p_2...p_n$$
Lhs has even factors, so Rhs must have $p_1=2$
$$\implies (p_2-1)...(p_n-1)d=2p_2...p_n$$
Rhs has only one $2$ , and all $p_i-1$ is even, so we must have 
$$\implies (p_2-1)d=2p_2$$ 
$p_2-1 \nmid p_2 \implies p_2-1 \mid 2$ but $p_2 \ne 2$ (so $1\mid 2$ isn’t allowed here) so
$2\mid 2$ $\implies p_2=3$
$\implies p_1=2$ and $p_2=3$ primes are allowed only. Checking the case, when $n=3^k$ doesn’t work, so a $2$ must be in the prime factorization. So the good number form is : $n=2^{k+1}3^s$ where $k\geq 0$ and $s\geq 0$.

I’d be happy if you comment better ones!

Comment: Jyrki's proof is simplifying and improving your proof.

Comment: Ohh thank you!! Sorry for duplicate

Comment: Also $\phi(1)|1$.  We don't need the factor of $2$ for that one case.